# RadGrid Filtering with Arabic Text

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, telerik

I have a RadGrid in asp.net application which is bound to a entity data source. Everything works great except filtering. I traced the query on SQL Server Profiler and found out `...where columnName like '%arabic text%'`  which is not returning any row. if you change this to`...where columnName like N'%arabic text%'` it gives you the correct result. Is there any solution or work around?.

Comment: always use N'text' while dealing with nvarchar columns

Comment: I know that, but how can I force telerik in-built filtering to use N.